# Get least accessed element in a List (Java 8)

Tags: java, list, java-8

I am trying to create an API wrapper.
This API requires an API key, like most do. My goal is to spread out the usage as evenly as possible between a list of API keys. This is needed to reduce the possibility of rate limiting.

Needs:

> Immutable List

A solution I could think of is to somehow get the least accessed element maybe with an object that keeps track of only the uses and the actual data? And then sort it and get the first element?

```java
class Key {
    private int uses;
    private UUID key;

    public Key(UUID key) {
        this.key = key;
        this.uses = 0;
    }

    public UUID get() {
        this.uses++;
        return this.key;
    }

    public int getUses() {
        return this.uses;
    }
}
```

I am up for using maven libraries such as Google Guava (which I am already using) if needed or for a more elegant solution. Here is an example of what it might look like.

```java
List<UUID> keys = new ArrayList<>();

public Data getDataFromApi(String name) {
    return getData(ENDPOINT_URL_STR + "key=" + keys.getLeastAccessed().toString() + "&name=" + name);
}
```

Comment: Are those keys added/deleted during the program execution or they always fixed?

Comment: Have you tried a PriorityQueue?

Comment: FYI, one technical label used commonly for this problem is: *least recently used (LRU) cache*. You can [search for Java LRU solutions](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=java+least+recently+used+(LRU)+cache&t=osx&ia=web).

Comment: @Flame239 they would be immutable. Forgot to add that to the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the set of keys would be immutable, I suggest implementing round-robin, i.e. you use 1st key, then 2nd, 3rd and so on until you reach nth and then you start over again from 1st key.

This way difference between usages of any 2 keys would be <= 1

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use Apache's `LRUMap` which removes the least recently used entry if an entry is added when full.

It sounds like what you are looking for. Documentation is [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/LRUMap.html)

Comment: I do not wish for any elements to be deleted.

Comment: LRU map is total overkill here

Answer (score 0):

If there is a list of mentioned `Key` instances, Stream API would be sufficient to get the least used elements using [`Stream::filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```java
public static List<Key> getLeastUsedKeys(List<Key> keys) {
    if (null == keys || keys.size() < 2) {
        return keys;
    }
    int minUsage = keys.stream().mapToInt(Key::getUses).min().getAsInt();
    return keys.stream().filter(k -> minUsage == k.getUses()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

If a single key is needed, [`Collectors.minBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#minBy-java.util.Comparator-) may be used:

```java
public static Key getLeastUsedKey(List<Key> keys) {
    if (null == keys || keys.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return keys.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.minBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Key::getUses)))
        .orElse(null);
}
```